# Is recommended to use Silex 2?

Tags: php, symfony, silex

In silex's web page, it says that the stable version of siles is 1.3 but  silex-skeleton uses version 2 of silex, is this recommended?

Answer (score 2):

<s>Silex 2.0 is not stable yet, in fact is a dev-master.</s> The bigger problem is that a dev-master can change at any time. Unlike a stable version, it may be that one day you will do `composer update` and your application will stop working for some reason.
It is always preferable stable versions, but you can also developed you application in sync with the branch master of silex.

Comment: and in case anyone comes across this question when googling like i did... silex 2.0.1 is now a released version.

Answer (score 1):

For your sake and the sake of your team **don't do it**.

I have made the mistake of putting one of my big projects back in time of Symfony2.0-alpha (or was it beta, not sure). The documentation was scarce, it was unstable for some use-cases - I wen't thought hell and back.

Projects are marked unstable for a reason - they should not be used in production until the devs make sable release.